# Free java library for Software Metrics

Tags: java, code-metrics

does anyone knows about a (free) java library that can calculate different software metrics given the source code? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: My comment is running a few years behind... but did you manage to find a library? I'm also looking for one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, give the [Eclipse Metrics Plugin](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/) a try.  [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/codesize.html) also has a set of rules relating to metrics.  There are a number of others; search StackOverflow for other questions about metrics tools.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. I don't need a tool to calculate metrics for a certain project. I am writing a tool that will perform Software Engineering related works, so I need a java library that I can use in my project to gather metrics (programmatically) from other target projects that my application will be processing.

Answer (score 0):

[CodePro analytix](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-codepro.html) from Google. This is just a eclipse plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. I don't need a tool to calculate metrics for a certain project. I am writing a tool that will perform Software Engineering related works, so I need a java library that I can use in my project to gather metrics (programmatically) from other target projects that my application will be processing